# Управление программой не используя графическую оболочку

Tags: linux, windows, bash, cmd, powershell

Подскажите, в ос windows реализована возможность управлять(любой) программой не используя графический интерфейс. Может cmd? powershell? Какие есть решения на эту тему? Может есть возможность такая в Linux?
Я знаю что можно запустить или закрыть. Но не больше. Может кто знает в каком направлении двигатся?

Comment: Если программа предоставляет управление через командную строку значит такая возможность есть, если нет то нет. И операционная система не причем. Можно только запустить процесс либо завершить его.

Comment: Обычный подход - это повторный запуск приложения с необходимыми ключами управления, которое при обнаружении уже работающей копии приложения передаёт всё это ей, а само завершает работу.

Comment: ,окей. Если даже так, в таком случае если в документации не указано, консольных команд, то в приложении значит их нет.  Это что один только способ? Возможно существуют способы определения наличия команд или способы обращения каким то методом?

Comment: мой мелофон подсказывает, что автору вопроса нужна какая-нибудь программа в духе `xdotool`.

Comment: Александ. Спасибо Вам за подсказку. Ваш мелофон не ошибся.

Answer (score 3):

За это отвечает не система а возможности самого приложения, если оно дает возможность управлять собой через input данные, то да, если есть только графический интерфейс, то соответственно доступа через консоль не будет. Запуск и закрытие идет просто из за того что это системная команда на выключения процесса. 
Кстати говоря, часто как раз наоборот, над консольными утилитами Т.Е над программами которые воспринимают только input поток из консоли, реализуют графический интерфейс, например GitHub desktop, это обертка над консольной утилитой git.

Answer (score 0):

Языки програмирования имеют свои библиотеки - к примеру в Python присутствует библиотека OS - при помощи нее можно делать многое. Хорошо развиты библиотеки по парсингу веб приложений. Существуют ли методы управления програмным обеспечением с командной строки и как бы к этому можно было подойти?
В общем можно подойти со стороны CLI, что интегрировано в sowftware, или если только GUI - тогда средства автоматизации или языки сценариев, поддерживающие автоматизацию графического интерфейса пользователя для взаимодействия с программой. Examples include tools like AutoHotkey, Sikuli, or scripting languages like Python with libraries such as PyAutoGUI or Selenium.
API or SDK